# Python classes: How should a built it

Tags: python, class, ros

I am trying to create a class called ListenerVilma that has two methods: "Clock_" and "Diagnostics_". Nevertheless both methods will call inner functions. The following code shows my attempt to achieve the mentioned behavior, but when I call ListenerVilma.Clock_() the get the following error:

> TypeError: unbound method Clock_() must be called with ListenerVilma instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

How should a create my class ListenerVilma???

Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from rosgraph_msgs.msg import Clock
from diagnostic_msgs.msg import DiagnosticArray

class ListenerVilma:
    """Class that listens all topics of the file vilmafeagri"""

    def Clock_(self):
        """Method that listens the topic /clock if the file vilmafeagri"""
        def __init__(self):
            self.listener()


        def callback(self, clock):
            print clock


        def listener(self):
            rospy.Subscriber('clock', Clock, self.callback)


    def Diagnostics_(self):
        """Method that listen the topic /diagnostics from rosbag file vilmafeagri"""
        def __init__(self):
            self.listener()


        def callback(self, diagnostics):
            print diagnostics


        def listener(self):
            rospy.Subscriber('diagnostics', DiagnosticArray, self.callback)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
   ListenerVilma.Clock_()
   rospy.spin()
```

Comment: Is Clock a class or a method? It looks like a class with the `__init__` method, but you used `def` for it

Comment: And assuming they are classes, why are they nested inside ListenerVilma? There is almost never a reason to nest classes in Python. Maybe ListenerVilma should be a module.

Answer (score 0):

the error is in line 41 in `ListenerVilma.Clock_()` here your directly using the method of your class so no implicit argument is pass and a instance of ListenerVilma is expected. The solution is `ListenerVilma().Clock_()` this first create a instance of your class and from say instance call its Clock_ method.

Outside that, your class construction is very weird, the [`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) is used to initialize a [class](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes) and a basic class construction is like this

```
class Foo:
    """example class"""

    def __init__(self,*argv,**karg):
        """initialize this class"""
        #do something with argv and/or karg according to the needs
        #for example this
        print "init argv", argv
        print "init karg", karg
        self.ultimate=42

    def do_stuff(self):
        """this method do something"""
        print "I am doing some stuff"
        print "after 7.5 million years of calculations The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything is: ", self.ultimate

    def do_some_other_stuff(self,*argv,**karv):
        """this method do something else"""
        print "method argv", argv
        print "method karg", karg

# basic usage            
test = Foo(1,2,3,key_test=23)
test.do_stuff()
test.do_some_other_stuff(7,8,9,something=32)
test.ultimate = 420
test.do_stuff()
```

I am not quite sure what you intentions are, but you build `Clock_` and `Diagnostics_` as a class, but they are not, and as right now they do nothing, if you want they to be class on their own do

```
class Clock_:
    def __init__(self):
        self.listener()

    def callback(self, clock):
        print clock

    def listener(self):
        rospy.Subscriber('clock', Clock, self.callback)
```

and the same with `Diagnostics_`, and I don't see a reason to the `listener` method so I would put what it does in the `__init__`, but maybe the rospy need it? I don't know, but for the looks of it then it should be used as

```
rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
Clock_()
Diagnostics_()
rospy.spin()
```

Answer (score -1):

The `Clock_` method doesn't belong to the class; it's an 'instance' method.
There are two options

- In the main function: create an instance of ListenerVilma: `listener = ListenerVilma()`, or
- In the `ListenerVilma` class: annotate the methods with `@classmethod` and make the class inherit from object: `class ListenerVilma(object):`. But remember, the first argument in your methods will be a reference to the class and not a reference to an instance.

Answer (score -1):

The following code performs better the behavior that I wanted. :)

```
class ListenerVilma:

    def CLOCK(self):

        def clock_sub():
            rospy.Subscriber('clock', Clock, clock_callback)

        def clock_callback(clock):
            print clock

        clock_sub()


    def DIAGNOSTICS(self):

        def diagnostics_sub():
            rospy.Subscriber('diagnostics', DiagnosticArray, diagnostics_callback)

        def diagnostics_callback(diagnostics):
            print diagnostics

        diagnostics_sub()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
    myVilma = ListenerVilma()
    myVilma.CLOCK()
    myVilma.DIAGNOSTICS()
    rospy.spin()
```